# Why the NIntegrate give the error "Integrand is not numerical \ at {x,y} =..." ., but at the values {x,y} the integrand can be evaluated?

Tags: numerical-integration

The integrand includes ku, Sin[x], and Tuu. ku is constant, x is one of the variables, and Tuu is functions of x and y.

According to the nice answer of KraZug, I have updated the program. I find that the program will give the errors "Integrand is not numerical \ at {x,y} =...", but at the given values {x,y} the integrand ku*Sin[x]*Tuu[x, y] can be easily evaluated. Why? How to solve the problem? Many thanks!

The updated codes are as follows.

```
Clear["`*"]
m = 2;
d = 2.106*(m + 1);
vh = 4;
mu = 11;
delta = 8;
HBAR = 1.05457266`14*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897`14*10^(-31);
ELEC = 1.60217733`14*10^(-19);
Kh = 2.106`14;
vKh[1] = {0, 0, 0};
vKh[2] = {Kh, 0, 0};
vKh[3] = {-Kh, 0, 0};
vKh[4] = {0, Kh, 0};
vKh[5] = {0, -Kh, 0};
vKh[6] = {Kh, Kh, 0};
vKh[7] = {-Kh, Kh, 0};
vKh[8] = {-Kh, -Kh, 0};
vKh[9] = {Kh, -Kh, 0};
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2]*10^(-10);
ku = kc*Sqrt[mu + delta];
kd = kc*Sqrt[mu - delta];
a3 = {Pi/Kh, Pi/Kh, Sqrt[2]*Pi/Kh};
kuu = {-SetPrecision[ku*Sin[x]*Cos[y], 12], -SetPrecision[
     ku*Sin[x]*Sin[y], 12], kz};
fuu[i_, i_] := Total[(kuu + vKh[i])^2] - ku^2;
fuu[i_, j_] := 
 If[i == j, fuu[i, i], 
  kc^2*vh*Total[
    Table[Exp[I*n*Total[(vKh[j] - vKh[i])*a3]], {n, 0, m}]]]
tuu = Array[fuu, {9, 9}];
sluu[xx_, yy_] := 
 sluu[xx, yy] = 
  Select[kz /. NSolve[Det[tuu /. x -> xx /. y -> yy] == 0, kz], 
   Re[#] >= 0 && Im[#] >= 0 &]
tduu[xx_, yy_, l_] := 
  tduu[xx, yy, l] = 
   tuu /. x -> xx /. y -> yy /. kz -> sluu[xx, yy][[l]];
nuu[x_, y_, o_] := nuu[x, y, o] = Flatten[NullSpace[tduu[x, y, o]]];
piuu[x_, y_] := piuu[x, y] = Transpose[Table[nuu[x, y, p], {p, 9}]];
pei = Table[If[q == 1, 1, 0], {q, 9}];
psiuu[x_, y_, u_] := 
  psiuu[x, y, u] = 
   Total[Table[
     LinearSolve[piuu[x, y], pei][[s]]*nuu[x, y, s][[u]]*
      Exp[I*sluu[x, y][[s]]*dd], {s, 9}]];
Tuu[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  Im[Total[Table[
     Conjugate[psiuu[x, y, u]]*(Dt[psiuu[x, y, u], dd]) /. 
      dd -> d, {u, 9}]]];
Guu := NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu[x, y], {x, 0.01, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 6];
Guu
```

Comment: One of the advantages of MMA is the ability to calculate symbolically. Your use of SetPrecision is dangerous , I think. Try to give exact parameters for example `HBAR=Rationalize[1.05457266*10^(-34), 0]` . On MMA 11.0.1. Your function ` `Tuuu[...]` doesn't evaluate in finite time...

Comment: The code contains errors. What are you trying to figure out? Which one do you solve the problem?

Comment: Use `=` instead of `:=` almost everywhere will help speed everything up. But currently `fuu[i,i]` is a vector of three elements instead of a value (like `fuu[i,j]`).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann When I give the values of x and y, Tuu can be evaluated within about 4 seconds. I have tried Rationalze, but there will be errors.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I do not find any errors, and the MMA also do not give any errors. Can you tell me where are the errors?

Comment: @KraZug fuu[i,i] is not a vector because I use the function "Total".

Comment: @user59546  Check `Plot3D[Re[Tuu[x, y]], {x, 0.01, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}]`, At the output you will receive many messages `Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{0.146161 +0. I,0.490986 +0. I,0.498288 +0. I,0.49461 +0. I,0.49461 +0. I},{},{},{},{-0.989237+0. I,0.0775496 +0. I,0.0688971 +0. I,0.072968 +0. I,0.0729675 +0. I}} cannot be transposed.` `Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev It is strange that my MMA does not give errors, but also can not give the figure. My MMA is 9.0, if it is the problem of version?

Comment: @user59546 Very sorry,I do not have a working version 9.0. I checked on 11.3, the functions `psiuu[u], Tuu[x, y]` are not defined in any point. Standard message `Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.`, `LinearSolve::matrix: Argument {} at position 1 is not a non-empty rectangular matrix.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Do you give the values of x and y? When you give the valuse of x and y (e.g. x=0.2, y=0.1), Tuu[0.2, 0.1] can be evaluated.

Comment: @user59546, sorry, I was trying to remove all the colons and removing that one didn't work.

Comment: @user59546 Of course, I calculated the functions for given numerical values. Checked on version 11.0.1 - the same error.

Comment: @AlexTrounev It may be due to the different versions.

Comment: @user59546 I checked the code on versions 8.0 and 10.3.0. Errors are revealed even more. What is unique about version 9.0, why are not errors detected on it?

Comment: @user59546 I found version 9.0 and version 10.0 on the old computer. I checked your code. All errors are the same as on versions 8.0 and 10.3. Check the code that you put here. And give us the equation that you are considering. It is possible that the code can be written much easier and it will work.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have checked the code just above, and there is still no errors. The idea of the program is as follows. tuu is a generated matrix containing kz. Through solve the equation Det[tuu]==0, one can obtained  the solutions kz. I substitute the solutions into tuu, and obtain tduu. Through NullSpace[tduu], I get the basic solutions nuu. Through LinearSolve piuu.A=pei, I get A=LinearSolve[piuu,pei]. Then, I construct psiuu and Tuu by A, sluu, and nuu. Now, Tuu is a function of x and y. At last,  I obtain the integration Guu=NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu[x, y], {x, 0.01, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}].

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think Tuu[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  Im[Total[Table[Conjugate[psiuu[u]]*(Dt[psiuu[u], d]), {u, 9}]] /. 
    d -> 2.106*(m + 1)] waste too much time because it should judge x and y if number. Is there any way to rewrite the program? Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexTrounev, can you write out the maths involved that you are trying to do.

Comment: @KraZug The maths I am trying to do is as follows. tuu is a generated matrix containing kz. Through solve the equation Det[tuu]==0, one can obtained the solutions kz. I substitute the solutions into tuu, and obtain tduu. Through NullSpace[tduu], I get the basic solutions nuu. Through LinearSolve piuu.A=pei, I get A=LinearSolve[piuu,pei]. Then, I construct psiuu and Tuu by A, sluu, and nuu. Now, Tuu is a function of x and y. At last, I obtain the integration Guu=NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu[x, y], {x, 0.01, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}].

Comment: Yes, I meant write it out properly using LaTeX and maths, not an unreadable comment. Check my answer though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82249/discussion-on-question-by-user59546-why-the-nintegrate-is-always-working-but-ca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you want. I have removed as many of the delayed evaluations (`:=`) as I could, used memoization to store the values of the others so they aren't calculated repeatedly and explicitly included $x$ and $y$ in the other definitions. Also, for some values of $x$ and $y$ the `Nullspace` wasn't working, giving errors of non-defined, so I decreased the tolerance there. Now my NIntegrate command is actually working, giving `2.11061` but with a warning about converging too slowly. Strangely, the value of `Tuu` doesn't seem to depend on $y$ very much at all - this comes back to `Det[tuu]` not seeming to have a strong dependence on $y$ either. If that is unexpected, then check what is going on.

Could certainly be optimized further.

```
Clear["`*"]
m = 3;
d = 2.106*(m + 1);
vh = 4;
mu = 11;
delta = 8;
HBAR = Rationalize[1.05457266`14*10^(-34), 0];
ME = Rationalize[9.1093897`14*10^(-31), 0];
ELEC = Rationalize[1.60217733`14*10^(-19), 0];
Kh = Rationalize[2.106`14, 0];
vKh[1] = {0, 0, 0};
vKh[2] = {Kh, 0, 0};
vKh[3] = {-Kh, 0, 0};
vKh[4] = {0, Kh, 0};
vKh[5] = {0, -Kh, 0};
vKh[6] = {Kh, Kh, 0};
vKh[7] = {-Kh, Kh, 0};
vKh[8] = {-Kh, -Kh, 0};
vKh[9] = {Kh, -Kh, 0};
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2]*10^(-10);
ku = kc*Sqrt[mu + delta];
kd = kc*Sqrt[mu - delta];
a3 = {Pi/Kh, Pi/Kh, Sqrt[2]*Pi/Kh};
kuu = {-ku*Sin[x]*Cos[y], -ku*Sin[x]*Sin[y], kz};
fuu[i_, i_] := Total[(kuu + vKh[i])^2] - ku^2;
fuu[i_, j_] := 
 If[i == j, fuu[i, i], 
  kc^2*vh*Total[
    Table[Exp[I*n*Total[(vKh[j] - vKh[i])*a3]], {n, 0, m}]]]
tuu = Array[fuu, {9, 9}];
sluu[xx_, yy_] := 
 sluu[xx, yy] = 
  Select[kz /. NSolve[Det[tuu /. x -> xx /. y -> yy] == 0, kz], 
   Re[#] >= 0 && Im[#] >= 0 &]
tduu[xx_, yy_, l_] := 
  tduu[xx, yy, l] = 
   tuu /. x -> xx /. y -> yy /. kz -> sluu[xx, yy][[l]];
nuu[x_, y_, o_] := 
  nuu[x, y, o] = 
   Flatten[NullSpace[tduu[x, y, o], Tolerance -> 10^(-12)]];
piuu[x_, y_] := piuu[x, y] = Transpose[Table[nuu[x, y, p], {p, 9}]];
pei = Table[If[q == 1, 1, 0], {q, 9}];
psiuu[x_, y_, u_] := 
  psiuu[x, y, u] = 
   Total[Table[
     LinearSolve[piuu[x, y], pei][[s]]*nuu[x, y, s][[u]]*
      Exp[I*sluu[x, y][[s]]*dd], {s, 9}]];
Tuu[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  Im[Total[Table[
     Conjugate[psiuu[x, y, u]]*(Dt[psiuu[x, y, u], dd]) /. 
      dd -> d, {u, 9}]]];
Guu := Monitor[
   NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu[x, y], {x, 0.01, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}], {x,
     y}];
Guu
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have further optimized the program according to your version. However, I find another problem. The errors say that Integrand 2.2331400000000 Sin[x] Tuu[x,y] is not numerical at {x,y} = {1.53075,0.392699}. But when I set x and y through copy the values, I find Tuu[x,y] can be evaluated. Why? How to solve this problem. The new codes have been updated as above.

Comment: Did you copy the full values that Mathematica gave (I.e. to more decimal places than the 5 given there)? The error is the same as I fixed by setting the tolerance of the nullspace, so I would start there.

Comment: I copy the full values. The error is because that the nullspace[tduu] gives {} due to the not enough precision. But now, nullspace[tduu] and Tuu give a valid result. I do not know why the NIntegrate give the error.

Comment: Using the same codes as your above answers, if set m=3, it also can not give a result with the same error " Integrand 2.2331400000000 Sin[x] Tuu[x,y] is not numerical at {x,y} = ....". Why?

Comment: @user59546, the code you have put into the question doesn't have the Tolerance on the Nullspace.

Comment: Remove the `SetPrecision`s, put the `Rationalize`'s back on the numerical constants, take out the `WorkingPrecision` in the `NIntegrate` and set the `Tolerance` to 10^-12. The exact same error as before, just the numbers you were getting out of the error message weren't precise enough to see it when you put them back into `Tuu` (I added a `Print[{x,y}]`; into the definition of `Tuu` to be able to copy them with more digits).

Comment: I have done as your suggestion. But if I set m=3, it does not work. Why?

Comment: Can I SetPrecision a variable, e.g.SetPrecision[ tduu[x, y, o]]?

Comment: I don't think you want to be setting precision of anything except the constants at the start, which is better done with Rationalize.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Has this solved your issue then? If you are planning on putting it into a loop varying m, make sure you clear the cached values of the functions btw.

Comment: Regretablly, if m is set as other values, e.g. 3, it does not work.

Comment: @user59546, with what error? It works fine for my code when I set `m=3`.

Comment: I have added updated code to my answer.

Comment: It is strange that the error "NIntegrate::inum: Integrand (1157533445822500272290389295104 Sqrt[19/2141165108423107299383623910728625019473074665] Sin[x] Tuu[x,y])/48828125 is not numerical at {x,y} = {0.985498,0.589049}." appears in  my MMA.

Comment: That is the same error, lower the `Tolerance` on the `Nullspace`. It works for me at $10^{-11}$ on Mathematica v9. For $m=50$, it works with tolerance = $10^{-5}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @user59546, if that solves all your problems, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: OK, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me how to mark? Thanks very much!

Comment: Click the tick under the answer you wish to accept (generally don't do this too early, best to wait at least a day in case better answers come along).